# HTML CSS Background-Color

Tags: html, css

http://paulsfiles.vacau.com/

I'm trying to add a background-color to `#maintext` but it isn't showing up. The body image seems to be over-riding the `#maintext`, even though `#maintext` is more specific.

Here's how I'm trying to lay it out.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/LIrsf.jpg]

The logical order I'm going for is the nav within the header, and the main text before the images. It's a fixed width site as well.

## [*jsFiddle*](http://jsfiddle.net/w9t48/)

Comment: place the code you tried to use and sample html, also it good to make jsfiddle

Comment: Oh right. I placed the code into jsfiddle. I'm new here sorry :) http://jsfiddle.net/w9t48/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Didn't you use the same color code `#6E6E6E` for `#maintext` and `#wrapper`?

Works fine for me if I change the color for `#maintext`. Hope that helps? Otherwise please come back to me :)

Comment: Wow that's embarrassing. I must be half colour-blind haha thanks man. I'm such a newb :)

Comment: @PaulRyan: If this answer solved your problem, consider upvoting and accepting it, by clicking on the large green tick mark (✔) under the answer's score.

Answer (score 0):

In `styles.css` line:115 you have this:

```
#maintext {
  float: right;
  width: 570px;
  background-color: #6E6E6E;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

That `background-color` happens to be the same one as the `#wrapper`. `#maintext` is not being overridden, at least not in the link you posted

Comment: Try changing the `background-color` with firebug in the browser, it works!